# Procfile working locally but not in heroku CLI

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli, npm-start, procfile

So I am trying to make my procfile for Heroku CLI but I don't think Heroku is recognizing it because when I do `$ git push heroku main` the Procfile doesn't work rather it does `npm start` rather than what's written in the Procfile but it works when I run it locally like `heroku local --procfile=procfile`. And I'm pretty sure that the P of my profile is correct so that's not the issue

When I do `$ git push heroku main` ( Updated ): https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGcSZ.png

When I do `$ heroku local --procfile=procfile`
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BErzz.png

Folder Pic:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/blHei.png

Procfile : `worker: node index.js`

Full git view + commiting :-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYOHw.png

package.json :

```
  "name": "ban-counter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^13.6.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: "I'm pretty sure that the P of my profile is correct"—I suspect it isn't: You've used both `Procfile` and `procfile` in your question (as well as `Heroku local` when it should be `heroku local`), and you're explicitly telling the CLI what to use as the `Procfile` via the `--procfile` argument. Is your file called `Procfile` or `procfile`? I'm betting the latter, and furthermore I'm betting you're on Windows.

Comment: that was autocorrect when I wrote in question .... I am 100% sure my P in `Procfile` is correct and Heroku too its Grammarly autocorrect ... also the `--procfile` you mentioned while using heroku local is according to a guide on Heroku ... https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands

Comment: Don't blame autocorrect. It is your job as a question asker to make sure you provide accurate information. Turn it off, manually fix its changes, whatever you have to do to make your question clear. We can't be expected to guess at which errors are relevant and which are typos.

Comment: ;-; ok i fixed the autocorrect thingy ( my fault ) but now can you please tell how to fix this issue so that when i do `git push heroku main` it takes whats in procfile as the code runner rather than default `npm start`

Comment: YEA man its called Procfile i have made projects in past with Procfile ...

Comment: my package.json has discord.js library in it

Comment: becuz its in heroku CLI commands guide and it is even working

Comment: then what do I do ... how do i make Procfile work with `$ git push heroku main` I dont wanna just run it locally

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577), and please include all output above "Release v3 created"—it contains useful information, including whether your `Procfile` is named with the wrong case (which I still suspect).

Comment: "how do i make Procfile work with `$ git push heroku main`"—by naming it correctly and putting it in the right place. You still have not shown that you've done this. Show the output of `ls` or a screenshot of your project's root directory.

Comment: Thank you. Now, is that file committed? What is the name of the branch you are trying to deploy? And what does Heroku tell you above "Release v3 created" when you push?

Comment: man I posted the pic of my folder so you can check my Procfile posting ls gimme 1 sec multitasking

Comment: it gives me a error cuz it freakin runs `npm start` whereas its supposed to run `node index.js` which is in Procfile

Comment: You continue to post screenshots of text. _Again_, [please don't do that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). Paste as _text_ into your question, then select and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K to format as a code block.

Comment: That last screenshot says "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 5 commits", but then `git push heroku main` says "up to date". Please show a graphical view of your commits and branches, e.g. via `gitk --all` or whatever other tool you prefer. Show all branches, please.

Comment: I already fixed the issue just had to add `"start": "node index.js"` to the scripts in the package.json ez

Comment: That's not a fix, it's a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to add `"start": "node index.js"` to the scripts in the package.json therefore now resulting in:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
     start": "node index.js"
  },
```